# java.util.MissingResourceException only on gluonfx:nativerun on android

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I am trying to build a gluon app with an MQTT client in it.
It works as intended on my computer with gluonfx:run. However, when running it from my android device I get the following error when initializing the MQTT client:
`Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat, locale en_US`

Does anyone know what might be going wrong when converting it to android code, and how I can fix it?

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.TimerPingSender.<init>(TimerPingSender.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:227)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.connectAndSubscribe(MQTTClient.java:87)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.connectAndSubscribe(MQTTClient.java:67)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.<init>(MQTTClient.java:58)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.<clinit>(MQTTClient.java:53)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.views.SendMQTTPresenter.sendMessage(SendMQTTPresenter.java:47)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.views.SendMQTTPresenter.lambda$initialize$4(SendMQTTPresenter.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3861)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1854)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2587)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:105)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleView.notifyMouse(MonocleView.java:116)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.notifyMouse(MouseInput.java:328)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.lambda$postMouseEvent$3(MouseInput.java:241)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:552)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:315)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.views.SendMQTTPresenter.sendMessage(SendMQTTPresenter.java:47)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.views.SendMQTTPresenter.lambda$initialize$4(SendMQTTPresenter.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3861)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1854)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2587)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:105)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleView.notifyMouse(MonocleView.java:116)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.notifyMouse(MouseInput.java:328)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.lambda$postMouseEvent$3(MouseInput.java:241)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:552)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.connectAndSubscribe(MQTTClient.java:92)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.connectAndSubscribe(MQTTClient.java:67)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.<init>(MQTTClient.java:58)
    at re.ledsco.testmqtt.mqtt.MQTTClient.<clinit>(MQTTClient.java:53)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Did you check https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_bundleslist ?

Comment: I did, but I don't understand how to add resources from a dependency to this list. It's not my own bundle that cannot be found, its a bundle from a dependency I use.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is in a dependency, you can always add the bundle's fully qualified name, `"org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat"` in this case?

Comment: That helped with my error but was followed by other errors. I realized that I would need to add a lot more manually, or I could use gluonfx:runagent. That goal wasn't set up as a selectable goal by default in the netbeans gluon plugin, but it was exactly what I was missing. Thanks for your help!